# Cakephp Warnings - failed to open stream

Tags: php, cakephp

This is my first time trying to use cake and i think im starting to go mental. I have absolutely no idea what is wrong with it! The files seem to be in the right place after checking.

In the system path cake is pointing to inetpub where as the application is in WAMP, would this have anything to do with it?

When i tried pointing the system path to WAMP, nothing happened! The Command console say cake is an invalid command...

Anyone know how to fix the errors below??

Any help is really appreciated

[image]

Comment: Are you sure you [installed cake correctly](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/view/912/Installation)?

Comment: I'll be honest with you, i'm not sure at all, i was trying to follow a video tutorial and this is where i ended up.

cheers for the link, i'll have a read of that and see if i can make sense of it

Comment: cheers dude! Slevin I like it, nicely picked up on!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you just need to change `CAKE_CORE_INCLUDE_PATH` in `APP/webroot/index.php` to find the core. That's why it can't find the bootstrap files.

Try first by uncommenting the line that defines the constant. If that doesn't work, you can try hardcoding a path to the cake core.